# Why shared library is loaded at a different address inside GDB for a target program as compared to free run?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

I am trying to debug a program with GDB.
The program runs correctly when run freely. It uses the shared library libc.so.6 which is loaded at address 0x7efff08.
But when i run the program in GDB, the loader loads the shared library libc.so.6 for the program at some other address. My program tries to read the library from the original address (0x07efff08), there it cannot find the ELF header, therefore gives error and terminates. (Invalid ELF header: could not load shared libc.so.6)

Note that I have disabled ASLR.

Is that something to do with shared library relocation? Both GDB and myprogram (being debugged) are using the same shared library.
How can I make sure that the library is loaded at the same address space for my process when run inside GDB?

Comment: You simply cannot rely on a hard-coded load address which will be always dynamically allocated. The only way to predict it would be in the case of a "closed system". You should load it yourself to get its address (`dlopen()`).

Comment: like while linking the libraries I can specify whether static or dynamic linking is desired, isn't there any option to prevent dynamic allocation?

Comment: @JulioGuerra Thanks for your input. Could you please tell me what do you mean by a "Closed system"?

Comment: What the output of "show disable-randomization" in gdb?

Comment: @JulioGuerra Could you explain why libraries will be loaded randomly once ASLR is disabled? Dynamic linker implements a fairly deterministic algorithm.

Comment: @ShakaibaMajeed FYI I can't repro this under Redhat 6.8 or Ubuntu 14.04 with a simple helloworld. There may be something special about your program or environment.

Comment: @yugr I didn't say "random", but "dynamic". Here, the dynamic allocation into the address space of the process is **supposed** to be **virtually** the same. But now that it's a GDB sub-process (`fork()`), it shares objects and thus memory regions with the parent (at least in the kernel), leading to different allocation addresses, the `brk()` address is also copied when forked. The assumption that dynamically allocated addresses are such strongly predictable is wrong. The only way to make it predictable is to statically allocate it (or use a deterministic and segregated OS).

Comment: @JulioGuerra Hm, following this logic processes executed in command line (i.e. `fork`ed by bash) would also have random library layouts but this does not happen. Debugged process is `exec`ed afterwards so all state coming from parent, including `sbrk` pointer, is reset.

Comment: What operating system and CPU do you see this on?  When you run the program under gdb, is the libc load address different every time you run it?

Comment: @yugr My System: Linaro 13.09 (GNU/Linux 3.12.0-rc5 armv71). I am using it on Exynos Arndale 5250 board. GDB version is 7.8. Configured as armv71-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.

Comment: @yugr output of "show disable-randomization" is "Disabling randomization of debugee's virtual address space is on"

Comment: @MarkPlotnick please see the version info in my above comment. No its not different everytime ..mostly two adresses 0x7effefa8 and 0x7effefb8. While in the free run it is always loaded at 0x7efff008

Comment: To explain more: I wrote myself a small tracer on the pattern of GDB, which forks the child process, exec'es it and plays it system call by system call. In that case the location of the shared library loading is always same like the free run.

Comment: Can you show the output of `(gdb) info proc map` ? It's possible that the address that libc is mapped to is affected by the size of the environment.  Gdb adds a few environment variables, such as LINES and COLUMNS.